# Hibernate mapping - insertable/updatable = false - can not set null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have hibernate-mapping for some Clazz and many-to-one relation for it:

```
    <property name="entityId" column="ENTITY" type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <many-to-one name="entity" column="ENTITY" class="Entity"  insert="false" update="false"/>
```

As said in the [community documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) :

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" property whose value is initialized from some other property that maps to the same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.

So, then I try to update Class with new entity, I just set new entityId field and and call `session.saveOrUpdate(clazz)` - everything works as expected and new entity is set in DB.

But if I try to set null (delete Clazz<->Entity relation) using

```
clazz.setEntityId(null)
```

then the corresponding COLUMN in DB is not updated and on next record retrieving I still get old not-null entity.

For experiment, I have tried to set entity object to null too (`clazz.setEntity(null)`) and - surprise! - it has worked!

Why do such things happen? Is setting to null not equal to update for Hibernate?

Additionally: On DB layer I have no triggers-like mechanisms affecting that property.

Hibernate version - 3.6.10.Final
OpenJDK 1.8.0_191

Comment: First, you should use a newer hibernate version. Second: move to annotations. those are much easier to read. Third: unless you use sequence/identity for the ID, ID always needs to have an value

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to upgrade hibernate and/or use Annotations now instead of xml-mapping. You know, sometimes legacy projects happen)